# Checking if file .endswith is in a list of extentions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a or loop that iterates over all the files in a directory and I'm trying to check if the files extension is in a list of extensions. I get the following error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'`

```
DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
EXTENTIONS = (".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xltx", ".xltm")
files = os.walk(DIRECTORY)

for file in files:
    if (file.endswith(EXTENTIONS)):
        # Do something here
```

Comment: Congrats! What is your question here?

Comment: learn how to use os.walk which returns a triplet. check the documentation

Comment: Unless you want to definitely want to `walk` sub-directories etc... then you probably want to use `os.listdir(DIRECTORY)` instead... otherwise... you need to adapt your code to follow the example given in the  [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) docs...

Comment: What is your question? Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk` returns a triplet of `root, directories, files`. You only need files here.

```
 DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  
 EXTENTIONS = (".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xltx", ".xltm")
 files = os.walk(DIRECTORY)

 for _, _, file in files:
    if (file.endswith(EXTENTIONS)):
       # Do something here
```

If you don't need to recursively traverse a directory, you can use `os.listdir()` here.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) properly. "it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`."

Since you want to check for multiple extensions, it would be faster to put them all in a `set` and check membership in that using the "`in`" operator which is a much faster because it uses a hash table instead of doing a linear search to check for matches:

```
import os

DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
EXTENTIONS = {".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xltx", ".xltm"}

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(DIRECTORY):
    for filename in filenames:
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if ext in EXTENTIONS:
            # Do something here
```